# Requests in queue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger, phusion

I am using phusion passenger open source but facing few problems

Passenger Version: 5.1.12
Nginx Version: 1.12.2

The site which we are using have 300+ users at a time, But within 5 minutes
`Requests in queue: 100` Sites get unresponsive

After a minute queue reduces to 0. It means no process is going to infinite its completing after a few minutes but this happens continuously.

I have set

```
passenger_max_pool_size 19;
passenger_min_instances 5;
```

We have `2 m4.xlarge` Aws instance with an ELB attached.

Using Rails 4 in backend

Earlier we had used puma and never faced this issue. Please suggest as am not getting any solutions.

Thank you

Comment: try with worker_processes  2; passenger_max_pool_size 20;passenger_min_instances 1;

Comment: worker_processes 4; #Its set to 4 now and queue looks normal

Comment: Before that please calculate optimal NGINX config. Otherwise your memory will overshoot. please check this thread: https://serverfault.com/questions/281199/nginx-how-do-i-calculate-an-optimal-no-of-worker-processes-and-worker-connecti